# What is the proper way to implement a copy constructor and operator for object pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Im trying to do a copy constructor and assignment operator for a Next and Prev object pointers but, Im not getting the right data when it tries to copy over. Im not sure if implemented this wrong.

Node.cpp

```
Node::Node(const Node& h) 
{
    Next = new Node(*h.Next);
    Prev = new Node(*h.Prev);
    data = h.data;
}

Node::~Node()
{
    delete Next;
    delete Prev;
}
Node& Node::operator=(const Node& t) 

{
    delete Next;
    delete Prev;
    Next = new Node(*t.Next);
    Prev = new Node(*t.Prev);
    data = t.data;
    return *this;

}
```

```
Node.H
Private: 
Node* Next;
Node* Prev;
int data;
```

Comment: Implenting a copy constructor and assignment operator for a `Node` of a linked list can be tricky. It is less tricky to implement the copy constructor and assignment operator of a container that uses the `Node` object. Something to think about.

Comment: In my case im trying to copy the Next and Prev pointers and they should come up as 0 when it verifys the copy but it doesn't.

Comment: With pointers only the owner of the pointer should call delete on it. Thus there **must** by only one owner. If you look at your node structure it has more than one owner (both the next and previous node own the current node as they will both call delete on the pointer to the current node).

Comment: Your question appears to be an **XY Problem**. See: [**What is the XY problem?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Draw a picture of your linked list, with nodes as rectangles and pointers as arrows. Now draw the  picture of the same list plus a copy of one of the nodes. What do you want the new picture to look like? Post it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a copy constructor for `Node`. It does not make sense to make a copy of a node.

A node is an element of a list. Should a copy be a duplicate node in that same list? But where in the list? At the head? At the end? At the beginning? It makes no sense.

Make a copy should be a duplicate node in a different list? But in what list? Again, it makes no sense.

Why do you think your `Node` class should have a copy constructor? What do you think it should do?

If you have an answer to that, then create a copy constructor. If you don't, *don't*.

The same logic goes for the assignment operator. What should it do? There's no obvious answer. So unless you have a precise idea of what it should do, *don't* write it.

Comment: I'll give you an example. Im copying Node B into Node C. Node c.GetNext needs to be 0 because that is what it is for Node B but, in my case it isnt.

Comment: I am more or so just trying to copy an pointer object. Im not trying to perform a deep copy in the class.

Comment: @Jay I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Say a Node is the fourth node in the middle of a list. You make a copy of that Node. What list should the copy be the fourth node of? Should that also be the fourth node of the same list so the list now has two fourth nodes? You are not making a copy of any pointer or reference, you code is the copy constructor *of the Node* for making a copy *of the Node*.

Comment: Also, your destructor makes no sense. Why are you destroying both the previous and next nodes? That will mean the previous node will destroy this node too (since this node is its next) and the next node will destroy this node too (since this node is its previous), thus destroying a node will destroy it three times. That also makes no sense. There is absolutely no reason destroying a node should also destroy other nodes. (If the code that's destroying this node also wants to destroy other nodes, that's its business.)

Comment: (When you write the destructor for a single instance of a Node, it should destroy a single instance of a Node. It shouldn't try to destroy anything else because that's the job of other code.)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Node::~Node()
> {
>     delete Next;
>     delete Prev;
> }
> ```

While a node is being destroyed, it destroys its successor. Which in turn destroys its predecessor, which destroys its successor, which destroys its predecessor, which destroys ... Can you spot the problem? This recursion is infinite. It never ends. Also, behaviour is undefined because you delete a pointer value that is already being deleted. Generally, list operations go only one way. You don't need to go back because that's where the algorithm "came from".

Even if we fix the problem by not going both directions, another problem with the recursion, is that it is as deep as the length of the list. Given that most systems typically have limited call stack size, this imposes an implicit limit for the maximum size of the list. Generally, linked list operations should use iteration instead of recursion.

Both problems occur in all shown functions.

> Im not trying to perform a deep copy in the class.

Then you've made a mistake since your copy constructor and assignment operator perform a deep copy - or at least they look like a broken versions of deep copy.

If you want shallow copy, then you want what the implicitly generated operations do. And if you do want shallow copy, then you also should want that the pointers are non-owning, and therefore would want to use the implicit destructor as well.